# Android, connecting to a specific wireless channel

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop

I live in a dorm where there is the same wireless network with different channels. How can I choose to which channel I want to be connected?

The problem is that channel 1, which has the best signal so gets automatically selected, is not working properly.

On my laptop I can just select the channel in wicd but I haven't found an app or possibility to connect only to specific channels in Android.

Android version is 5.0.2

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: first gen Moto G